# each function return wrong logical value

Tags: r

I am trying to integrate 2 functions. 
The first one is to check if the variable is dummy or not while 
the second applies to a data frame and return a print statement based on the value of each column (dummy or not).
The dummy function works fine with single variables (e.g. df$var1) but when i try to use the second one on a dataframe it shows that all the variables are dummy when they are not.
here the code

Some randomly generated data

```
level=c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither agree or disagree","Disagree", "Strongly disagree",NA)
df <- data.frame(pre_1=as.character(sample(c("Yes","No", NA), 20, replace = T)), 
                                    pre_2=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                                    post_1=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                                    post_2=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                                    stringsAsFactors=T)
```

Here the dummy function

```
dummy <- function(v, naVal = NULL) { 
  v1 <- na.omit(v)
  # remove NA's
  v2 <- as.integer(as.factor(v1))
  if( !is.numeric(v2) ) stop("Only numeric vectors are accepted.")
  # get unique values
  v_unique <- unique(v2)
  # remove 'naVal's
  v_unique2 <- v_unique[! v_unique %in% naVal]
  # count number of unique values and check whether all values are integers
  if ( length(unique(v_unique2)) > 2L || 
       any(as.integer(v_unique2) != v_unique2) ) FALSE else TRUE
}
```

Here the print function for the df

```
data_dummy <- function(df) {
    df = select(df, starts_with("pre_")) 
    for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
      if (dummy(as.character(df[i]))==TRUE) {print ("dummy")}
      else {print ("not dummy")}}
}
```

The expectation should be 1 "dummy" 1 "not dummy".
Reality:

```
[1] "dummy"
[1] "dummy"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common error, and a good one to keep your eye out for when things aren't working the way you'd expect. You're extracting a data frame using `[i]` when you expect to extract a vector. To extract a vector, use `$name` or `[[i]]`. Here's the fix that requires the fewest characters to be changed:

```
data_dummy <- function(df) {
  df = select(df, starts_with("pre_")) 
  for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    if (dummy(as.character(df[[i]]))==TRUE) {print ("dummy")}
    else {print ("not dummy")}}
data_dummy(df)
# [1] "dummy"
# [1] "not dummy"
```

If you want to practice defensive programming, though, avoid using brackets to extract in general. This prevents the inevitable typo, and, I think, makes it more readable as well. If you want to loop through the columns of a data frame, then do that. Notice in particular, `for (col in df)`

```
data_dummy <- function(df) {
    df = select(df, starts_with("pre_"))
    for (col in df){
        if (dummy(as.character(col)) == TRUE) print("dummy")
        else print("not dummy")
    }
}
data_dummy(df)
```

Comment: what's the difference between df[i] and df[[i]] ??
Btw it worked like a charm.

Comment: Amazing, answer. Thanks a bunch

Comment: `?Extract` and `?Extract.data.frame` are helpful reads, if you want the nitty gritty details :)